# setTimeout / setInterval mobile browser to calculate cpu efficiency

Tags: javascript

The cpu efficiency of how to use setTimeout / setInterval to calculate mobile browser?

```
function fn() {
    var start = new Date();
    setInterval(function () {
        var _s = new Date();
        console.info(_s - start);
        start = _s;
    }, 1000/60)
}
fn()
```

Comment: How does it relate to `css3`?

Comment: possible duplicate (or at least related): [Are there any standards for mobile device web browsers in terms of thread sleeping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739835/are-there-any-standards-for-mobile-device-web-browsers-in-terms-of-thread-sleepi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use console.time:

```
function someFunction(){
    console.timeEnd('someFunction timer');
    //this function's code goes here...
    console.time('someFunction timer');
}
```

This will give you the time your function took to execute. Is this what you needed?

Or maybe this?

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

//your code
var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;
alert('Execution time: ' + time);
```