# Issue creating valid test case for promise rate limit function

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to create a valid test case for the `promiseRateLimit` function below. The way the `promiseRateLimit` function works is it uses a `queue` to store incoming promises and will place a `delay` between them.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

export default function promiseRateLimit (fn, delay, count) {
  let working = 0
  let queue = []
  function work () {
    if ((queue.length === 0) || (working === count)) return
    working++
    Promise.delay(delay).tap(() => working--).then(work)
    let {self, args, resolve} = queue.shift()
    resolve(fn.apply(self, args))
  }
  return function debounced (...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      queue.push({self: this, args, resolve})
      if (working < count) work()
    })
  }
}
```

Here's an example of the function in action.

```
async function main () {
  const example = (v) => Promise.delay(50)
  const exampleLimited = promiseRateLimit(example, 100, 1)
  const alpha = await exampleLimited('alpha')
  const beta = await exampleLimited('beta')
  const gamma = await exampleLimited('gamma')
  const epsilon = await exampleLimited('epsilon')
  const phi = await exampleLimited('phi')
}
```

The `example` promise takes `50ms` to run and the `promiseRateLimit` function will only allow `1` promise every `100ms`. So the interval between promises should be greater than `100ms`.

Here's a complete test that sometimes returns successful and sometimes fails:

```
import test from 'ava'
import Debug from 'debug'
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import promiseRateLimit from './index'
import {getIntervalsBetweenDates} from '../utilitiesForDates'
import {arraySum} from '../utilitiesForArrays'
import {filter} from 'lodash'

test('using async await', async (t) => {
  let timeLog = []
  let runCount = 0
  const example = (v) => Promise.delay(50)
    .then(() => timeLog.push(new Date))
    .then(() => runCount++)
    .then(() => v)
  const exampleLimited = promiseRateLimit(example, 100, 1, 'a')
  const alpha = await exampleLimited('alpha')
  const beta = await exampleLimited('beta')
  const gamma = await exampleLimited('gamma')
  const epsilon = await exampleLimited('epsilon')
  const phi = await exampleLimited('phi')
  const intervals = getIntervalsBetweenDates(timeLog)
  const invalidIntervals = filter(intervals, (interval) => interval < 100)
  const totalTime = arraySum(intervals)
  t.is(intervals.length, 4)
  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
  t.deepEqual(totalTime >= 400, true)
  t.is(alpha, 'alpha')
  t.is(beta, 'beta')
  t.is(gamma, 'gamma')
  t.is(epsilon, 'epsilon')
  t.is(phi, 'phi')
})
```

I've created a `getIntervalsBetweenDates` function that simply diff's two unix timestamps and get the duration between an array of dates.

```
export function getIntervalsBetweenDates (dates) {
  let intervals = []
  dates.forEach((date, index) => {
    let nextDate = dates[index + 1]
    if (nextDate) intervals.push(nextDate - date)
  })
  return intervals
}
```

***The issue is that the test above sometimes returns an interval that is lower than the `delay`. For instance if the `delay` is `100ms` sometimes an interval returns `98ms` or `96ms`. There is no reason this should ever happen.***

Is there any way to make the above test pass 100% of the time? I'm trying to ensure that the `delay` argument works and that there is at least that much time between promises.

*Update 2016-12-28 9:20am (EST)*

Here's the full test

```
import test from 'ava'
import Debug from 'debug'
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import promiseRateLimit from './index'
import {getIntervalsBetweenDates} from '../utilitiesForDates'
import {arraySum} from '../utilitiesForArrays'
import {filter} from 'lodash'

test('using async await', async (t) => {
  let timeLog = []
  let runCount = 0
  let bufferInterval = 100
  let promisesLength = 4
  const example = v => {
    timeLog.push(new Date)
    runCount++
    return Promise.delay(50, v)
  }
  const exampleLimited = promiseRateLimit(example, bufferInterval, 1)
  const alpha = await exampleLimited('alpha')
  const beta = await exampleLimited('beta')
  const gamma = await exampleLimited('gamma')
  const epsilon = await exampleLimited('epsilon')
  const phi = await exampleLimited('phi')
  const intervals = getIntervalsBetweenDates(timeLog)
  const invalidIntervals = filter(intervals, (interval) => interval < bufferInterval)
  const totalTime = arraySum(intervals)
  t.is(intervals.length, promisesLength)
  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
  t.deepEqual(totalTime >= bufferInterval * promisesLength, true)
  t.is(alpha, 'alpha')
  t.is(beta, 'beta')
  t.is(gamma, 'gamma')
  t.is(epsilon, 'epsilon')
  t.is(phi, 'phi')
})

test('using Promise.all with 2 promises', async (t) => {
  let timeLog = []
  let runCount = 0
  let bufferInterval = 100
  let promisesLength = 1
  const example = v => {
    timeLog.push(new Date)
    runCount++
    return Promise.delay(50, v)
  }
  const exampleLimited = promiseRateLimit(example, bufferInterval, 1)
  const results = await Promise.all([exampleLimited('alpha'), exampleLimited('beta')])
  const intervals = getIntervalsBetweenDates(timeLog)
  const invalidIntervals = filter(intervals, (interval) => interval < bufferInterval)
  const totalTime = arraySum(intervals)
  t.is(intervals.length, promisesLength)
  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
  t.deepEqual(totalTime >= bufferInterval * promisesLength, true)
})

test('using Promise.props with 4 promises', async (t) => {
  let timeLog = []
  let runCount = 0
  let bufferInterval = 100
  let promisesLength = 3
  const example = v => {
    timeLog.push(new Date)
    runCount++
    return Promise.delay(200, v)
  }
  const exampleLimited = promiseRateLimit(example, bufferInterval, 1)
  const results = await Promise.props({
    'alpha': exampleLimited('alpha'),
    'beta': exampleLimited('beta'),
    'gamma': exampleLimited('gamma'),
    'delta': exampleLimited('delta')
  })
  const intervals = getIntervalsBetweenDates(timeLog)
  const invalidIntervals = filter(intervals, (interval) => interval < bufferInterval)
  const totalTime = arraySum(intervals)
  t.is(intervals.length, promisesLength)
  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
  t.deepEqual(totalTime >= bufferInterval * promisesLength, true)
  t.is(results.alpha, 'alpha')
  t.is(results.beta, 'beta')
  t.is(results.gamma, 'gamma')
  t.is(results.delta, 'delta')
})


test('using Promise.props with 12 promises', async (t) => {
  let timeLog = []
  let runCount = 0
  let bufferInterval = 100
  let promisesLength = 11
  const example = v => {
    timeLog.push(new Date)
    runCount++
    return Promise.delay(200, v)
  }
  const exampleLimited = promiseRateLimit(example, bufferInterval, 1)
  const results = await Promise.props({
    'a': exampleLimited('a'),
    'b': exampleLimited('b'),
    'c': exampleLimited('c'),
    'd': exampleLimited('d'),
    'e': exampleLimited('e'),
    'f': exampleLimited('f'),
    'g': exampleLimited('g'),
    'h': exampleLimited('h'),
    'i': exampleLimited('i'),
    'j': exampleLimited('j'),
    'k': exampleLimited('k'),
    'l': exampleLimited('l')
  })
  const intervals = getIntervalsBetweenDates(timeLog)
  console.log(intervals)
  const invalidIntervals = filter(intervals, (interval) => interval < bufferInterval)
  const totalTime = arraySum(intervals)
  t.is(intervals.length, promisesLength)
  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
  t.deepEqual(totalTime >= bufferInterval * promisesLength, true)
})
```

I'm still getting the issue even with the `example` change.

```
[ 99, 98, 105, 106, 119, 106, 105, 105, 101, 106, 100 ]

  2 passed
  2 failed

  using Promise.props with 4 promises

  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
              |                    
              [99]                 

  Generator.next (<anonymous>)

  using Promise.props with 12 promises

  t.deepEqual(invalidIntervals, [])
              |                    
              [99,98]              

  Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: are you referring to the `97`? setTimeout (which is what Promise.delay uses under the hood) isn't millisecond perfect - though using a very simple test I've never seen a 100ms timeout take **less** than 99ms, but that's not to say it can't happen

Comment: That's nuts that `Promise.delay` isn't millisecond perfect.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: it's odd though, I did a simple test with a loop of 100 setTimeout - and the smallest timeout was 99 ... there is a *nodejs high precision timer* with setTimeout, if you look for it using google

Comment: @JaromandaX I disagree that it's a timer thing, I've throughly tested my `getIntervalsBetweenDates` function with `Promise.delay` in between and I'm getting no unexpected results. There is something wrong with the `promiseRateLimit` function that allows rate limited promises functions to run too close to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` (which is internally used in `Promise.delay`) does not guarantee accurate timing, <s>it only ensures that the callback is invoked *not before* the given timeout expires</s>. The actual timing will depend on machine load, the speed of the event loop, and [possibly anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10740558/1048572).

In fact, the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) only state that

> The `callback` will likely not be invoked in precisely `delay` milliseconds. Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when callbacks will fire, nor of their ordering. The callback will be called as close as possible to the time specified.

What will happen in your tests is that `Promise.delay(50)` sometimes takes longer than 50ms (not by much, but still), and the difference to the following log can become less than 100ms when the next `Promise.delay(50)` is more on time.

You should be able to mitigate this effect if you simply log the invocation times of your `example` function immediately, not after the artificial delay of *about* 50ms:

```
const example = v => {
  timeLog.push(new Date);
  runCount++;
  return Promise.delay(50, v)
};
```

To deal with the inaccuracy of the 100ms timeout itself, the easiest solution is to give it some leeway of maybe 5% (which makes 5ms in your case):

```
const invalidIntervals = filter(intervals, (interval) => interval < 100 * .95)
t.true(totalTime >= 400 * .95)
```

If you want to be absolutely sure that the delay is never too short, you can write your own function:

```
Promise.delayAtLeast = function(delay, value) {
    const begin = Date.now()
    return Promise.delay(delay, value).then(function checkTime(v) {
        const duration = Date.now() - begin;
        return duration < delay
          ? Promise.delay(delay - duration, v).then(checkTime);
          : v;
    });
};
```

and use that in `promiseRateLimit`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I was very hopeful when I applied this, but It's still returning less then 100ms times I added the latest test above and the results from the test.

Comment: I've replaced all the calls to `Promsie.delay` to the your `Promise.delayAtLeast`  I've detected that `Promise.delayAtLeast` does fire cases where the delay wasn't met. It's failing on cases where `duration < delay` is `false`. Meaning the delay worked correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? Are you saying the returned promise still fulfils too early?

Comment: Yes the promises return too early.

Comment: That's weird, this mustn't happen. Are you sure you didn't forget the `return` in the `then` callback or something?

Comment: Here's an exact example code of what's running and it's failing. Really apreciate your help so far @Bergi! Feel no obligation to assist further. https://github.com/reggi/example-for-promise-rate-limit

Comment: Hm. The last idea that comes to my mind is that you should move [the delaying of `work`](https://github.com/reggi/example-for-promise-rate-limit/blob/master/src/utilitiesForPromises/index.js#L20) two lines down, below the work (`fn.apply(…)`). Oh, and btw `tap` should be `finally`

Comment: OMG I think moving the `Promise.delay` below `fn.apply` worked! Not sure why. I replaced all the delays back to `Promise.delay` and it's working 100% so far.

Comment: Well, there's some stuff happening between the `setTimeout` (in `Promise.delay`) and the `new Date` (in `example`/`fn`), i.a. the creation of three promise objects and the mutation of the `queue`. It should be quite rare, but it's still possible that they don't happen in the same millisecond.