# Two recursive functions try to execute at the same time when only one should run

Tags: javascript

Essentially, I am trying to create a webpage that has 2 buttons; one will cause the screen to flash randomly, and the other will cause it to slowly change colours. I want to be able to switch between these two (if you press the first button it starts flashing and then if you press the second button it slowly changes without any kind of cancel button).

The buttons each call a function which sets the 'running' variable of the other function to false and it's own 'running' variable to true. It then calls a recursive function (recursive in that it just calls itself over and over). These recursive functions only execute their code when their 'running' variable is true.

If you run the snippet you can see that the program is very inconsistent (you may need to play with it for a bit to see the issue since it sometimes seems to work). Sometimes it refuses to change function and other times the two functions seem to both be active and they both try to execute (it almost looks as if they are fighting for control). I don't understand how this is happening since, I believe, only one of the 'running' variables can be true at any time.

```js
var runningDisco = false;
var runningColours = false;


function startColours() {
  if (runningDisco == true); //Is disco running?
  {
    runningDisco = false; //If yes, stop it
  }
  runningColours = true; //Indicate we are running
  window.setTimeout(Colours, 100, 0); //Run
}

function startDisco() {
  if (runningColours == true); {
    runningColours = false;
  }
  runningDisco = true;
  window.setTimeout(Disco, 100);
}

function Disco() {
  if (runningDisco == true); {
    hex = "#";
    for (discoCount = 0; discoCount < 6; discoCount++) {
      hex = hex.concat((Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)).toString(16));
    }
    document.body.style.background = hex;
    window.setTimeout(Disco, 10);
  }

}

function Colours(colourCount) {
  if (runningColours == true); {
    if (colourCount > 359) {
      colourCount -= 359;
    }
    document.body.style.background = "hsl(" + colourCount + ", 50%, 50%)";
    window.setTimeout(Colours, 10, colourCount + 1);
  }

}
```

```css
input {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dd1021;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Start Disco" onclick="startDisco();" />
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Start Colours" onclick="startColours();" />
```

Comment: I don't understand your title. is it a question or what? please make the title clearer

Comment: Running the same function with `setTimeout` is not really recursion.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said  _recursive in that it just calls itself over and over_ .not really sure what the correct name for something like this is

Comment: Maybe the word *recurring* is more appropriate then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semicolons after your if-statements are causing a problem

For example, replace:

```
 if (runningColours == true); {
 if (runningDisco == true); {
```

with

```
 if (runningColours == true) {
 if (runningDisco == true) {
```

[Here it is fixed in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y48xfuct/).

Comment: Yes, I appear to have added in an if statement and forgotten to remove them, then copied the if statement elsewhere

Comment: Actually, no. With or without the semicolon, the result is always the same - `runningColours` is set to `false` after this.

Comment: @Bergi in the "start" functions you are correct, but in the `Colours` and `Disco` functions, this is what is causing the problem

Comment: I see. But your answer didn't state that.

Comment: @Bergi the answer stated: "...the semicolons after your if-statements are causing a problem" which was accurate. The problem was that the OP was putting semicolons after if statements.

Comment: ONE problem was that. A LOGICAL problem is not clearing the intervals when switching

Comment: @mplungjan true, but once the if() statements were fixed, the code was defensive enough so that there would be no effect to not clearing the intervals

Comment: Because everything is inside an if. Much more elegant to use a timeout handler.

Comment: @mplungjan absolutely agreed. But not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have semicolons in the wrong place
2. If you need to run a single animation you need to use a single global variable to hold the timeout handler and clear it when starting a new one.

Like this:

```js
var running;

function startColours() {
  clearTimeout(running);
  running = setTimeout(Colours, 100, 0); //Run
}

function startDisco() {
  clearTimeout(running);
  running = setTimeout(Disco, 100);
}

function Disco() {
    var hex = "#";
    for (discoCount = 0; discoCount < 6; discoCount++) {
      hex = hex.concat((Math.floor(Math.random() * 17)).toString(16));
    }
    document.body.style.background = hex;
    running = setTimeout(Disco, 10);

}

function Colours(colourCount) {
    if (colourCount > 359) {
      colourCount -= 359;
    }
    document.body.style.background = "hsl(" + colourCount + ", 50%, 50%)";
    running = setTimeout(Colours, 10, colourCount + 1);
}
```

```css
input {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dd1021;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Start Disco" onclick="startDisco();" />
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Start Colours" onclick="startColours();" />
```

Comment: It's a nice suggestion but has nothing to do with the problem the OP was asking about

Comment: @SkinnyJ Not really. Original problem OP is trying to solve was "... I want to be able to switch between these two". His code is XY-problem. And I provide a better solution to the original problem. Otherwise this question should be closed as it was just a typo.

Comment: @mplungjan True. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

You made a common mistake to those new to JavaScript - including a semi-colon after you if header. This creates an if statement with no body that is followed by a block containing the single statement runningColours = false, which will not execute correctly. The below should fix this:

```
if (runningColours == true)
{
    runningColours = false;
}
```

The following JSFiddle link should have a working version of your script:
https://jsfiddle.net/4qhmtnhe/
I hope it starts working, and you continue to learn JavaScript.

Comment: The if statement does nothing and the code in the bracers is always executed.

Comment: This is more an issue in the recursive functions, Disco and Colours, as it means that they continually run.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is the semicolons after the `if` statements inside the `Disco` and `Colours` functions:

```
if (runningDisco == true); {
  document.body.style.background = …
}
```

will execute as

```
if (runningDisco == true)
  ;
{
  document.body.style.background = …
}
```

which runs the content regardless of the boolean variable. Why does it work at all sometimes? I guess when the two `setTimeout` callbacks run close enough to each other that only the latter is rendered at all it feels consistent. Of course that is [very unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10740558/1048572) - they are indeed fighting each other for screen time.