# Measure network latency in React Native

Tags: performance, react-native, fetch-api, latency, runloop

What would be the best way to measure network latency in React Native?

E.g.

```
const startTime = Date.now(); 
let response = await fetch(url)
const endTime = Date.now(); 
const totalTimeInMs = endTime - startTime;
```

If I place start and stop timer before/after the network call as shared above that might not give true network latency because the JS might be busy doing some other work and would come to this eventually when there is nothing in the event loop / call back queue / task.

Hence wondering if there is any better way to measure network latency?

Comment: if you do that in a blocking part of your code(such as async funcs), it will give you an accurate measure i think

Comment: dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752454/how-to-calculate-the-execution-time-of-an-async-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while looking for ways to measure just request-response time in `axios`....but I thought it was interesting enough to have an alternative answer to the core question.

If you *really* want to know the **network latency** the technique used by the [Precision Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) could be some inspiration.

**The concept**
This drawing hopefully explains what I mean by "network latency":

```
     API Request             API Response
        |                          ^
        v                          |
  UI ---+--------------------------+-----------> Time
       A \                         ^ B
          \                       /
           \                     /
            \                   /
             v                 /
 Backend -----+---------------+-------------> Time
            a |               ^ b
              |               |
              +- processing --+
                    time

Where:
 - A is the time when the UI sends the request
 - a is the time when the backend receives the request
 - b is the time when the backend sends the response
 - B is the time when the UI receives the response

The time it takes from A->a is the network latency from UI->backend.
The time it takes from b->B is the network latency from backend->UI.

Each step of request/response can calculate these and add them to 
the respective request/response object.
```

**What you cannot do with this**

- You probably won't be able to precisely sync the clocks this way, there will be too much jitter.
- You can't really also tell the inbound/outbound latency. As you have no way to know the relationship in time of `A` to `a`, or of `B` to `b`.

**What you might be able to do with this**
The total time seen in the UI (`B - A`), less the total time seen in the backend (`b - a`), *should* be enough to get a good estimate of the round-trip network latency.

i.e. `network_latency = ((B-A) - (b-a)) / 2`

Averaged over enough samples this might be good enough?

*FWIW, you could just have the backend include its own "processing_time" in the response, and the UI could then store "A" in the context of the request and calculate "B-A" once a successful response comes back. The idea is the same though*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-native-debugger to get the familiar network tab from web development for use in react-native!

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/network-inspect-of-chrome-devtools.md

Answer (score -1):

## Solution 1:

install [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library

```
yarn add axios
```

`response.latency` will give the totalTimeInMs

**Full Code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const axiosTiming = (instance) => {
  instance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
    request.ts = Date.now();
    return request;
  });

  instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    const timeInMs = `${Number(Date.now() - response.config.ts).toFixed()}ms`;
    response.latency = timeInMs;
    return response;
  });
};
axiosTiming(axios);

export default class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.latency);  //17ms
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> test </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

by using fetch, but fetch does not give us default timing attributes

```
const start = new Date();
 return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
   const timeTaken= (new Date())-start;
  return responseJson.movies;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not explain how we can accurately measure network call.

Comment: @Yahoo I have updated my answer you can test latency

Comment: I wonder how internally does axios handle this? looking at this, I feel `axios` also does not slow it as it is a JS way of doing things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752454/how-to-calculate-the-execution-time-of-an-async-function-in-javascript

Comment: @Yahoo are using interceptors of Axios like middleware of Axios and we calculating time inside of middleware, therefore, no external factor affect it

Comment: Downvoted. Measuring how long your target service take to give you some data back do not represent the network latency (rtt) at all. What if your target service take 5 minutes to process your request, will you put that on the network or your target service ?