# Is it possible to share a const to scope outside a block or closure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

Take this example function

```
async function foo () {
  const res = await fetchData()
  const out = await processData(res)
  return out
}
```

Imagine that I notice `fetchData` is slow and I want to quickly profile with a generic timer function / generator:

```
async function foo () {
  for (let time of timer()) {
    const res = await fetchData()
  }
  const out = await processData(res) // error res is undefined
  return out
}
```

This now breaks the code as `res` is no longer defined. I could define `let res` before the block, or use `var` but that means modifying source code for some temporary profiling code. I guess this is the very point of `const` is [scoping to statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). However, I still feel there is a way of maintaining scope and triggering an event before and after a set of lines?

I am not married to generators. Closures could do the same job but have the same scoping issue. Other syntax suggestions welcome.

How can I wrap some arbitrary block of code but maintain the variable scope? Maybe with [a proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)? Something similar to context managers from python. This could be on the edge of the limitations of the language?

Comment: seems like you can use profiling function that accepts a callback or promise and returns it's result

Comment: You've already identified the two solutions (predefine with `let` or use `var`).  If you move a `let` or `const` declaration inside a block, you narrowed its scope to only that block.  There's no way around that - that's the language definition.  By wrapping it in a block, you narrowed the scope of the variables defined in that block with `const` or `let`.  No way around that without changing the code inside the block.

Comment: Note that implementing a profiling timer as a generator would be a huge mistake. Generator functions incur a huge performance loss due to the nature of their interruptable control-flow. If you don't believe me, try benchmarking a generator function vs. an equivalent for loop.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this is just for profiling so it will almost never be in production. A generator is fast enough for my requirements. However I am open to any other syntax. I am not married to generators, callbacks or blocks

Comment: I don't see an issue with using `var`, but I am guessing there must be various profiling options that don't require any code changes

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of something like this?

```
async function timed(p) {
  const start = performance.now();
  const res = await p();
  const end = performance.now();
  console.log('time elapsed', end - start);
  return res;
}

async function foo () {
  const res = await timed(fetchData);
  const out = await processData(res);
  return out
}
```

Comment: That won't work because you called `fetchData` before `timed` and also I want this to work for an arbitrary number of lines

Comment: Since `fetchData` is a promise, it likely returns right away. If you want to capture multiple, you can just wrap them in an async anonymous function. You'll only be able to get a single return value though.

Comment: `fetchData()` -> `fetchData`, `await p` -> `await p()`

Comment: Also, `performance.now()` has microsecond resolution (returned as a floating-point millisecond value) while `Date.now()` only has (unreliable) millisecond resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "*quickly profile `fetchData` with a generic timer function / generator*". All I can see is that you moved the statement into a loop, where obviously it might be executed multiple times or not at all, so you cannot easily assign one result value to an outer-scope `res` variable.

If you want to use a loop over some data structure, yes just use `let res` and get the last value from the loop (or the initial value in case the loop body didn't run).

If you want to profile the `fetchData` function, have a look at [How to measure the execution time of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44158044/1048572).