# Window.setTimeout(f, 0) waits a lot when browser (Chrome) idles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout

I am analyzing performance of existing UI application using Chrome developer tool and have noticed a really strange behavior - from time to time (about 5-10%) browser just idles before executing the script from setTimeout().
I've googled a lot, and I've found a lot of answers that browser puts the script into the end of queue, so it waits until all other tasks are finished.

**Yes, but it waits a lot more! From 10ms to 800ms more!**

Chrome performance tool

[image]

The code which sets this timeout looks pretty much like: `y.setTimeout(a, 0)`

- Is it a Chrome 65 issue?
- Is it real or can be seen only in developer tool?
- Is there a way to eliminate this and force script to execute ASAP after the time has come (in this case - immediately after other tasks have been finished)?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10740558/1048572)

Comment: "*Is there a way to force script to execute ASAP after the time has come (in this case - immediately after other tasks have been finished)?*" -  What is the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you need this for?

Comment: @Bergi The actual problem is overall performance of the page. It often fails to finish everything in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs?rq=1): this happens when tab is inactive, because timers in inactive tabs fire once a second, so waiting "overhead" is floating from 0 to 1 second.
Feels like not a real performance problem for users, but a real problem for our performance measurements...